# Placing limits on stars and bars theorem

Tags: combinatorics

Is there any way to place upper and lower limit while obtaining result from the stars and bars theorem?

Basically, I want to find the number of integer solutions to $a+b+c= 6$ where $a,b,c \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$

The number of non negative integer solutions to it is $\dbinom 8 6$. But this is without contraints on a,b and c.

This is obviously an easier problem and can be done using cases, but what about the tougher ones where $n$ and the limits are large?

Answer (score 1):

$a+b+c=6$ where $a,b,c \in \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6\} = {8\choose 6}$

As you said above.

How to deal with the constraint?

Exclude the cases where $a$ or $b$ or $c \in \{5,6\}$

How do we do that?  Put $5$ stars in one bin.  There are ${3\choose 1}$ bins that could be the overfilled bin.  And 1 remaining star that you are free to allocate ${3\choose 1}$

${8\choose 6} - 3\cdot 3 = 19$

In more extreme examples.... you will need to use the inclusion-exclusion principle.

e.g. how many ways are there to roll a sum of $20$ on four 6-sided dice?

${19\choose 3}-4\cdot {13\choose 3} + {4\choose 2}{7\choose 3}$

Comment: Please explain how you excluded the case of 5 and 6. I am unable to understand.

Comment: How many ways are there for $a+b+c = 6$ assuming $a,b,c$ are all positive and one of $a,b,c \ge 5$ ?  lets assume that $a\ge 5$ let $d = a-5$  how many ways are there for $d+b+c = 1$?  Now do the same thing considering when each of the cases where $b,c \ge 5$

Comment: what about a+b+c =8, $a,b,c \in \{0...5\}$?

Comment: Generating functions would be another way to solve these types of problems: e.g. for the last question in this answer, it's $[x^{20}] (x+x^2+\cdots+x^6)^4 = [x^{20}] \left( \frac{x^4 (1-x^6)^4}{(1-x)^4} \right)$.